# Rank function gives incorrect Ranking

Tags: sql, sql-server, dense-rank

```
select distinct a.pattern ,convert(numeric(18,0) ,isnull(b.[DCount]as [DCount]
,DENSE_RANK () OVER ( Partition by a.pattern order by b.[DCount]desc ) as [Rank]  
from a, b
```

Gives output as

```
Pattern Dcount  Rank
A   0   1
A   0   1
A   0   2
A   0   2
B   0   2
B   0   2
B   0   2
B   0   2
C   0   2
C   0   2
C   0   2
```

Whereas required output is

```
Pattern Dcount  Rank
A   0   1
A   0   1
A   0   1
A   0   1
B   0   1
B   0   1
B   0   1
B   0   1
C   0   1
C   0   1
C   0   1
```

Comment: Code is broken due to missing parenthesis

Comment: How about `1 as rank`?  Why do you need a function?

Comment: Rest assured, the `RANK` function works as documented, so does the `DENSE_RANK` function. However, your query doesn't  parse (incorrect brackets to begin with) and you don't explain your expectations. Its very hard to answer without more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you just want the ranking by `dcount`.  If so:

```
select distinct a.pattern, convert(numeric(18,0),
       coalesce(b.DCount, 0) as DCount,
       dense_rank() over (order by b.[DCount] desc) as [Rank]  
from a cross join b;
```

Answer (score 0):

use `DENSE_RANK` below way

```
select * ,DENSE_RANK () OVER ( order by Pattern, Dcount) as rn from t
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: you need to partition by Pattern,dcount and order by only pattern

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6a0783af183ba9cccccc520a5efdce5e)

```
select *,dense_Rank() over(partition by Pattern,dcount order by Pattern) from tablename
```